# Сделал викторину на js, хотелось бы услышать критику

Tags: javascript, html, css, инспекция-кода

```js
let li = document.getElementsByTagName('li');
let h = document.getElementsByTagName('h1');
let click = 0;
let score = 0;
let radio = document.getElementsByName('radio');
let input = '<input name="radio" type="radio">';
let quizz = document.getElementsByClassName('quizz');
let innerScore = document.getElementById('score');
document.getElementById('go').addEventListener('click', questionPush);

let arr = [
  ['', '', '', '', '', 1],
  ['Что такое CSS?', 'Hypertext Preprocessor', 'HyperText Markup Language', 'Document Object Model', 'Cascading Style Sheets', 3],
  ['Что такое HTML?', 'Cascading Style Sheets', 'Document Object Model', 'HyperText Markup Language', 'Hypertext Preprocessor', 2],
  ['Что такое PHP?', 'Hypertext Preprocessor', 'HyperText Markup Language', 'Document Object Model', 'Cascading Style Sheets', 0]
];

function questionPush() {
  test();
  innerTest();
  h[0].innerHTML = arr[click][0];
  li[0].innerHTML = input + arr[click][1];
  li[1].innerHTML = input + arr[click][2];
  li[2].innerHTML = input + arr[click][3];
  li[3].innerHTML = input + arr[click][4];
}

function innerTest() {
  if (click < arr.length - 1) {
    click++;
  } else {
    quizz[0].classList.add('hidden');
    innerScore.innerHTML = "Ваш результат: " + score + " из " + arr.length
    innerScore.classList.remove('hidden');
  }
}

function test() {
  if (radio[arr[click][5]].checked) {
    score++;
  }
}
```

```css
.quiz {
  margin: auto;
  height: 400px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #61B4CF;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: #024E68 2px solid;
  position: relative;
}

button {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  border: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 100px
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#score {
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: #024E68;
  margin: 150px auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #61B4CF;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="quiz">
  <div id="score" class="hidden"></div>
  <div class="quizz">
    <h1 class="question">Что такое DOM?</h1>
    <ol>
      <li><input name="radio" type="radio">Cascading Style Sheets</li>
      <li><input name="radio" type="radio">Document Object Model</li>
      <li><input name="radio" type="radio">HyperText Markup Language</li>
      <li><input name="radio" type="radio">Hypertext Preprocessor</li>
    </ol>
    <button id="go">go</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

*Welcome to magic numbers hell:*  `radio[arr[click][5]].checked`

---

```
let questions = [
  // ['', '', '', '', '', 1], - ???
  {
    text: 'Что такое CSS?',
    answers: ['Hypertext Preprocessor', 'HyperText Markup Language', 'Document Object Model', 'Cascading Style Sheets'],
    correct: 3
  },
  ...
];

function questionPush() {
  test();
  innerTest();

  document.querySelector('.quizz .question').textContent = questions[click].text;
  var list = document.querySelector('.quizz ol');
  list.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < questions[click].answers.length; i++) {
    var item = document.createElement("li");
    item.innerHTML = '<label><input name="radio" type="radio"><span></span></label>';
    list.appendChild(item);
    item.querySelector("span").textContent = questions[click].answers[i];
  }
}
```

И не помещайте html с первым вопросом на страницу изначально. Создавайте его кодом, как и все остальные.

Comment: А в исходном варианте порядок ответов отличается в разных вопросах. :)

Comment: @Yaant не понял. В моем варианте он тоже может отличаться.

Comment: А, сорри, был сильно невнимателен. :)) Показалось, что берется один и тот же список ответов. :)

Comment: @Yaant Рад, что дело прояснилось ).

Comment: А как в этому скрипту добавить форму ввода телефона и почты и всё это отправить на почту